# VB.NET: How to add more than one control to WinForm programmatically

Tags: vb.net, winforms, controls

I'm trying to add labels to my form on the timer tick event. It adds the first label no problem, but doesn't seem to add any more.

After some debugging I can see that the controls are added but it only ever displays the first label. Is there something I'm missing here?

```
Private Sub timTick1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles timTick1.Tick
    iTick1 += 1
    lblTick1.Text = iTick1

    iPhase += 1
    lblPhase.Text = iPhase

    Select Case iPhase
        Case 1
            Phase1()
        Case 2
            Phase2()
        Case 3
            Phase3()
        Case 4
            Phase4()
    End Select

    If iPhase = 4 Then
        iPhase = 0
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Phase4()
    Panel3.Controls.Add(New Label With {.Text = "TESTING" & iTick1, .Location = New Point(iTick1, iTick1)})
End Sub
```

Comment: The Location property you assign is not correct, 4 pixels is not enough.  The second label will be *underneath* the first label so you can't read its text.  Use a proper Location or use the label's BringToFront() method.

Comment: Thank you, the BringToFront() method worked. I understand that the label was rendering under the first, but I don't understand why I didn't see the 20th or 100th or 1000th label as it would be rendered outside the original label.

Anyhow this all seems to be working now; it was more of a proof of concept. Thank you.

Comment: You would have had to set the BackColor or BorderStyle property to see it.